# Populate TextBoxFor values when DropDownList on change from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a list of user profiles that is returned in my model. The name of the user profile is returned in the DropDownList. When I select a name in the DropDownList I need to populate the TextBoxFor with the relevant values.

My model is;

```
public class Profiles
{
    public List<ProfileList> profiles { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileList
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; } 
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

My code snippet is;

```
<div class="row init-row">
     <div class="col">
          <div class="label-count">
              @{ var paxNo = i + 1;}
              @Html.Label("PASSENGER #", "PASSENGER #" + paxNo.ToString())
          </div>
          @{
             List<SelectListItem> otherPax = new List<SelectListItem>();
             otherPax.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "SELECT A PROFILE", Value = "0" });
             foreach (var pax in Model.profiles)
             {
                otherPax.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = pax.firstName + " " + pax.surname, Value = idString });}
                @Html.DropDownList("otherProfile", otherPax)
             } 
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col">
                  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.passengers.otherPassengers[i].Id)
                  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.passengers.otherPassengers[i].title, Titles.TitleListItems(), "TITLE")
               </div>
        </div>
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
                   <div class="col-2">
                        <div class="input-wrap">
                             @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.passengers.otherPassengers[i].firstName, new { id="firstName", placeholder = "First name" })
                        </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
           </div>
                   <div class="col">
                       <div class="input-wrap">
                           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.passengers.otherPassengers[i].lastName, new { placeholder = "Last name" })
                       </div>
                   </div>
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col">
                      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.passengers.otherPassengers[i].dateOfBirth, "{0:ddMMyyyy}", new { @class = "date", id = "dateOfBirthOtherPax", placeholder = "DATE OF BIRTH" })
                   </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: listen to the change event on the SELECT element ,get the selected value and get details using the value (may be make an ajax call passing the value and server can look up that value and return the details as json which you can use in your ajax call's success call back to fill the textbox

Comment: Thanks Shyju, as I have the data in the ProfileList model I was hoping that I would not have to call the server each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by using multiple events on the onchange handler